# When do implants drop?

Tags: planetside-2

Implants have been added to the game recently. You can obtain a random one from "things such as capturing bases, killing enemies, and potentially support actions and alerts". That's too vague for my taste.

So exactly what actions can award an implant? Is it just random chance for each action, or is there some internal counter that triggers an award at specific intervals? Are all such actions equal in terms of implant awards?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implants drops are based on XP events, are random and higher awared XP have a higher chance for an implant drop.

> Fact is: the current drop tuning is designed to allow average players (by raw, non-boosted xp gain, 
>   across all characters) to be able to maintain even tier 3 implants with drops alone. Check it out 
>   for yourself. The loot system is more complex than just "kills per implant drop" or "xp per implant 
>   drop", it's weighted and favors large xp events (base captures, ribbons, alerts) for better drops. 
>   No one has scratched the surface of the drop system on pts yet. - Higby (PS2 Creative Director)

Source: http://www.reddit.com/r/Planetside/comments/240luz/smedly_on_implant_drops/ch2qiq1?context=3

Initially there were caps in place for drop rates but they got removed at 21.05.2014.

Source: https://twitter.com/mhigby/status/469329397690822656

There are not more information available about the inner workings of the drop system.

Comment: This is no longer correct as they have substantially revamped how implants work.

Answer (score 0):

Implants drop randomly. Just play the game and you will receive tier 1 and sometimes tier 2 implants and chargers. Also you can craft from low tier implants higher tier implants.